# Migration list with all items

Tags: list, migration, backup

Is there any solution to copy a list with all fields and the name of the user who originally created the item? When I migrate from the backup list it uses my administration name.

Comment: You want to copy programatically?

Comment: Not at all someone copy.

Comment: do want to move with in site collection? or moving to different site collection or farm?

Comment: Only move a list with Created By field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Powershell, be sure to use the parameter `-includeusersecurity.`

But be careful as this backups all the permission up to the site collection tier. It wont matter if you do it from Central Admin ( clicking 'export full security' ) or Powershell. You must do it this way to retain the user data for all the list items.

[Be cautious while using '-includeusersecurity' in Export/Import Tool](http://sharepointcampus.blogspot.se/2012/11/be-cautious-while-using.html)

[Export sites, lists, or document libraries in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: But why Beware ?

Comment: Say that you are moving a list to site collection A by using a backup, then it will add all the permission groups from site collection A to site collection B. Do some testing and check the permissions groups after.

Comment: After Export And Import it bring me all groups to the SiteColection, but they are empty. I tried a User which have got a permision, and his not have a permision to new list, but new groups made. CanI delete them ?

Comment: Wen they are blank

Comment: And how I Could move a Created By without bring all grups to the site colection ?

Comment: You cant. If you read the first link to the blogpost, it's a choice between keeping your data intact and bringing the security groups, or have your data without the created by, created, modified by and modified. Simple as that, yet irritating.

Comment: And You know any disandvantage about to delete all from this created groups after moving list ? Can I delete them after moving ? Are they connected with any Site Colection or lists. I try to this list, after migration the user which can see this list can't see this list so it meybe don't conecting this list with any group.

Comment: You are correct, the groups that came with the export does not give any new permissions. I think you can delete the groups that followed with the export from the UI och Designer. The groups that are site permissions are those in use, the rest is just groups that followed with the export.